# What does it mean "Process finished with exit code 0" in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm junior Java Developper and I'm new to use IntelliJ IDEA.
When an app ends or finishes it says Process finished with exit code 0 or 1, and sometimes -1, and I don't actually know the meaning of these codes.
Thank you for telling me the difference between those numbers.

Comment: Error codes other than 0 (which is success) usually means an uncaught exception and should be accompanied by a message in the terminal explaining what happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

0 usually means the process terminated normally with no error condition. Other codes generally indicate a specific error condition, but the meaning varies depending on the process.  In Java, your application can set a return code using `System.exit()`. If JVM encounters a low-level error or uncaught exception, it's also possible it could return a non-zero value instead of the value explicitly returned by your application.